# WPF: Как получить текст, выделенный в ячейке DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf

Такая проблема: необходимо осуществить поиск по выделенному тексту, допустим, пользователь выделяет часть текста в ячейке и необходимо вывести только те записи, в которых присутствует эта часть текста (точнее в столбце, где и выделялась часть текста). 
Data grid хранит простенькие объекты с 5 полями. 
Всё столбцы типа textcolumn.

Даже не знаю как получить выделенный текст из ячейки

Comment: А пользователь выделяет текст где? В ячейке DataGrid?

Comment: И на какое действие вы хотите фильтровать записи? При нажатии на кнопку? или когда?

Comment: Андрей, да, пользователь выделяет текст в ячейке Datagrid.

Comment: И да, фильтровать записи необходимо по нажатию на кнопку

Answer (score 1):

Получить выделенный текст из ячейки можно, например, следующим образом: подпишитесь на `PreparingCellForEdit`, и там:

```
private void OnPreparingCellForEdit(object sender, DataGridPreparingCellForEditEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.EditingElement is TextBox textBox)
    {
        textBox.SelectionChanged += OnSelectionChanged;
    }
}
```

В `CellEditEnding` надо отписать от события:

```
private void OnCellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.EditingElement is TextBox textBox)
    {
        textBox.SelectionChanged -= OnSelectionChanged;
    }
}
```

Здесь `OnSelectionChanged` — метод:

```
private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    PatternTextBox.Text = textBox.SelectedText;
}
```

Разметка:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBox x:Name="PatternTextBox"
             Text="{Binding Pattern, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

    <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Search"
            Command="{Binding SearchCommand}"/>

    <DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
              PreparingCellForEdit="OnPreparingCellForEdit"
              CellEditEnding="OnCellEditEnding"/>
</Grid>
```

Фильтрацию коллекции `Items` реализуете в команде `SearchCommand` по тексту в свойстве `Pattern` в вашей VM.

Comment: Премного благодарен